# How to get python bytecode?

Tags: python, bytecode

I've tried using `py_compile` to get me some bytecode examples (for learning needs).

However, this is what I get

**file.py:**

```
print("hello world")
```

**file.pyc:**

```
 U

��Ob   �                   @   s   e d � dS )zhello worldN)�print� r   r   �test.py�<module>   �
```

I guess I'm doing something terribly wrong, but I have no clue.

My base script is

```
import py_compile

py_compile.compile('test.py')
```

Comment: You're printing binary data, so that's what it's supposed to look like... What else did you expect exactly?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I guess im doing something terribly wrong, but i have no clue." What do you think it should look like instead? Why? Also, what exactly are these "learning needs"? Also, you can get Python to compile any file by simply `import`ing it as a module.

Comment: Did you expect to see the instruction names instead of bytecode?

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille Ty for all replies, i was away for a while, sorry. Main idea was to see by my own eyes the difference between lists and tuples for example. And i've read in Mark Lutc's book about the bytecode and i was sure that bytecode and binary data are different things. LIke bytecode goes to PVM and becomes binary. DIS is smething that is really what i was hoping to see. Thanks!

Comment: @nachtblume Also bytecode *is* binary data. It's "machine code" for a virtual machine, not machine code of the physical target platform.

Comment: @nachtblume As an explanation: Python source code is compiled by the interpreter into python bytecode, which is a type of binary data. The interpreter then executes this binary code. The `dis` module can turn this binary data into a human-readable format of operators and operands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for (the) `dis` module ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html))?

Example:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo(a):
...   return a * a
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Some words about the relation between raw bytecode and the disassembled mnemonics would make this answer even better. The questioner and future readers seem to have difficulties to distinguish between both.